# Calculating Mbps based on duration and filesize

Tags: computer-science

Let's say I download a file that is `3500` bytes in `2401` milliseconds. What is the calculation to work out Internet speed?

I ask because I'm developing a piece of software that does just this to make a guess at the users current internet speed. My problem is I don't how to use these 2 numbers to calculate the Mbps.

Here's what I've got so far. Not sure if I'm on the right track but I'm getting the wrong result.

1. I convert the bytes to bits by multiplying the bytes by 8
2. Divide the bits by the number of seconds it took to transfer the file to get bits per second
3. Divide by 1,000,000 to get the Mbps

`Mbps = ((fileBytes * 8) / durationInSeconds) / 1000000`

If I put my numbers into this function I get a completely different result:

```
((3500) * 8) / 2.401) / 1000000
(28000 / 2.401) / 1000000
11661.80758017492711 / 1000000
= 0.01166180758017
```

The result `0.01166180758017` is not correct as my Internet speed is ~4Mbps. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your math is right, the download speed turns out to be abysmal because of other issues.

Try a (significantly) bigger file. (I mean *a lot bigger*: 100s of MBytes.) Otherwise, the actual download time is swamped by the time it takes to connect to the host and exchange all the other messages (e.g. SSL/TLS handshake if you run over HTTPS), plus the time the host itself takes to respond.

Comment: Ah, this might be a problem. The constraints of the test I'm performing mean the download can take no longer than a second. Is it completely impossible to make a close estimate to the users possible download speed?

Comment: Also to add, the result of the duration of the download is the actual time it took to download minus the handshake etc. So the `2041` is the actual time it took to download the file.

Comment: @BugHunterUK I don't know. At 4Mbit/sec, the actual download of your 3500-byte file would take 0.007 sec. Where was the rest (2.041 sec - 0.007 sec = 2.034 sec) spent? I don't know. You will need to figure it out and eliminate those factors. In my answer I pointed to a few usual culprits, but I cannot comment on what is the problem in *your* particular  setup. Have you tried to run the network monitor software (e.g. Wireshark) and see the packets?
 Anyway we are leaving the realm of mathematics and going into software/hardware: maybe this site is not the best place to discuss those issues?

Comment: Very good point. And agreed. I'll chew this over tonight. Thanks for your input it has been useful. Oh also I am not looking for the users ISP speed but their current internet speed at that moment in time.

Comment: Over two seconds to download a tiny file (3500 bytes will fit in two Ethernet packets!) is way too long a delay to be accounted for by handshakes and server latency unless the server is seriously unwell. @BugHunterUK, are you sure you haven't inadvertently counted microseconds instead of milliseconds, or something like that? Also, "current internet speed" in practice is a very hard concept to pin down -- so hard that it is arguable whether it exists at all.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I was thinking that possibly it also took the time to store the file on the disk, scan it via Anti-Virus, which itself had to connect to its cloud during the scan as many of them do... Who knows... The OP needs to sort it out.